# The reward for the creation of spiritual benefits (Pirkei Avot)

Tags: mishna, chabad, pirke-avot-ethicsof

I am reading the wonderful collection of sichos of the Rebbe זי"ע called [Torah Studies](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/110248/jewish/Torah-Studies.htm) edited by Rav Jonathan Sacks ז״ל. In the lecture on the parashah of Chayei Sara, the Rebbe says "the reward for the creation of spiritual benefits is ascribed to the deceased", and the note refers us to Pirkei Avot, 5:8. But unfortunately, there is no mention of this issue in the quoted passage of the Pirkei Avot. Does someone know where to locate the place in the Pirkei Avot where this issue is discussed?
Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you show us a sicha that mentions this concept, ideally the one that refers this mishna? thank you

Comment: Did you look in the sichah of  לקוטי שיחות - ה ? - https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=14928&st=%d7%90%d7%91%d7%95%d7%aa&_rnd=0.11456688818725103

Comment: The sicha I am referring to is [Chayei Sara](https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/110321/jewish/Torah-Studies-Chayei-Sarah.htm). The passage I quoted is towards the end of paragrpah 7.

Comment: @Shmuel Dear Shmuel, unfortunately my knowledge of Hebrew is still quite elementary, and I cannot read the original text of the לקוטי שיחות.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a misprint in the original sicha (footnote 40). It should be [Avot 5:18](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.18?lang=bi):

> Moses was righteous and caused the multitudes to be righteous, [therefore] the righteousness of the multitudes is hung on him

Comment: Thank you very very ... much @shmosel for having kindly answered my question!